# Haskell, Char, Unicode, and Turkish

Tags: text, unicode, haskell, localization, internationalization

For the Char data-type, how do I specify that I want to use the Turkish i instead of the English i for the toLower and toUpper functions?

Comment: Favorited. turkish is tricky due to dotless I issues. It is the best test-case for such functions.

Comment: Understanding monads is a cakewalk compared to handling Unicode correctly.

Comment: @Alex: Turkish? Not to mention German's multi-letter uppercase ß -> SS and Greek's context-dependent lowercase Σ -> σ/ς.

Comment: turkish messes up the ascii part of unicode, hence a good test-case.

Comment: I think the German case is unfair. One would not expect a function that returns a Char to be able to return a pair of chars.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: By that argument, a `toUpper` function on Unicode characters must either be incorrect or return a string. Neither is terribly appealing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**text and the text-icu package**

As of 2011, your best bet is to use the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package, and the `toLower` function of [the Text ICU package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu), which supports `Char` operations parameterized by a locale,

From [this example](http://ersiner.net/2010/09/27/case-mapping-for-turkish-in-haskell/):

```
import Data.Text (pack, unpack)
import Data.Text.ICU (LocaleName(Locale), toLower)

main = do
  let trLocale = Locale "tr-TR"
      upStr    = "ÇIİĞÖŞÜ"
      lowStr   = unpack $ toLower trLocale $ pack upStr
  putStrLn $ "toLower " ++ upStr ++ " gives " ++ lowStr
```

Running this:

```
> toLower ÇIİĞÖŞÜ gives çıiğöşü
```

while this example converts between `String`, you can also just leave the data in `text` format.

Answer (score 16):

The `Data.Char` library in Haskell is not locale dependent. It works for all Unicode characters, but perhaps not in the way you would expect. In [the corresponding Unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) you can see the mappings for "dotted"/"dotless" i's.

- `toUpper 'i'` => `'I'`
- `toUpper 'ı'` => `'I'`
- `toLower 'I'` => `'i'`
- `toLower 'İ'` => `'i'`

Thus, it is clear that neither of the two transforms are reversible. If you want reversible handling of Turkish characters, it seems you have to use either a C-library or roll your own.

**UPDATE:** The [Haskell 98 report](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/char.html) makes this quite clear, whereas the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch16.html) only says that `Char` corresponds to a Unicode character, and does not as clearly define the semantics of `toLower` and `toUpper`.

Comment: `toLower 'I'` should give a dotless `i`.

Comment: @Alexandre: I documented how Haskell work, and what the (linked) Unicode specification says. If you want other behavior, you need to implement your own (as in jrockway's reply).

Answer (score 8):

A Simple Matter Of Programming:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

toLower 'I' = 'ı'
toLower x   = Char.toLower x
```

Then

```
toLower <$> "I AM LOWERCASE" == "ı am lowercase"
```

Comment: Are you really telling me that I have to hack every library that calls Char.toLower in order to support internationalization?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, because the Haskell specification only says to follow the Unicode standard, which provides the rules I gave above. Thus any library that uses `Char.toLower` is not prepared for internationalization.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: If you don't want the standard Unicode behavior, then no, you can't use libraries that follow the Unicode standard. It's unfortunate, but pretty plainly so.

Comment: I should clarify that this is not the best possible solution.  It would be good to write a library that is more flexible than Data.Char, and the community would surely appreciate any contributions in that area.