# haskell: read in special characters from console

Tags: haskell, unicode

I'd like to read in a string from console which contains special characters like ö,ä,ü,µ... I've tried:

do ...
   ts <- getLine
   ...

but this doesn't work for those character. For example, unicode for ö is \246, but if I use getLine to read in ö haskell reads in "\195\182", and putStr "\195\182" gives me Ã¶, which is not ö. What's the problem here? Do I need another function to read in those characters?

I am using WinGHCi 7.0.3 on windows xp. I'd be glad if someone could help me because I didn't find anything so far.

---

@Judah Jacobson:

I tried it again, before typing any other commands, and got this:

```
Prelude> :m +System.IO
Prelude System.IO> hSetEncoding stdin utf8
Prelude System.IO> getLine
ασδφ
"\206\177\207\402\206\180\207\8224"
Prelude System.IO> putStr "\206\177\207\402\206\180\207\8224"
Î±ÏƒÎ´Ï†Prelude System.IO>
```

I also tried the windows command    chcp 65001   but it didn't change anything, I had utf8 already activated in windows.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode+haskell?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: What is your code page? Try typing this command: `chcp 65001` in the console and run your Haskell program again, do you still see this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I still have the same problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the encoding of stdin to UTF8. For me, this is set to CP437 initially in GHCi on Windows XP, and to UTF8 on Mac.

Check with `hGetEncoding stdin` (System.IO), and set with `hSetEncoding stdin utf8` and it should work.

**Edit**: This is what it looks like on my Mac:

```
Prelude System.IO> hSetEncoding stdin latin1
Prelude System.IO> str <- getLine
ö
Prelude System.IO> putStr str
Ã¶Prelude System.IO> print str
"\195\182"
Prelude System.IO> hSetEncoding stdin utf8
Prelude System.IO> str <- getLine
ö
Prelude System.IO> putStr str
öPrelude System.IO> print str
"\246"
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, hGetEncoding stdin (System.IO) gives me: Just CP1252. hSetEncoding stdin utf8 doesn't change anything...

Comment: Strange... certainly changes this on my machine - see above.

Comment: I was always trying to do it in console, now that I have integrated    hSetEncoding stdin utf8    into my source code all works fine. Obviously one cannot change the codepage of WinGHCi from console...

Answer (score 3):

Since GHC 6.12 strings are handled as UTF8 in input and output  (or with some other encoding, based on your locale setting). So make sure your locale is set to e.g. UTF8.

You can also manually control this stuff via the [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412577/haskell-char-unicode-and-turkish/5758213#5758213) package, which supports many other locale conventions and encodings.

Comment: No one should use `text` for a simple task like this.

Comment: Well, the author should probably just check their locale setting. However, it is good to know that you can always do it yourself if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "set my locale to UTF8"? I have UTF8 activated in windows and there are no such settings for ghci, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error; this looks like a bug in WinGHCi.  By default, GHC on Windows uses the Win32 "console code page" to encode and decode Handle I/O.  However, WinGHCi sends input to GHC as UTF8-encoded bytes, but incorrectly has the code page set to 1252 (Latin-1).

I was able to work around this bug using Mike Hartl's answer: run `hSetEncoding stdin utf8` before performing any line-input commands.  For example:

```
Prelude> :m +System.IO
Prelude System.IO> hSetEncoding stdin utf8
Prelude System.IO> getLine
ασδφ
"\945\963\948\966"
```

If that doesn't work for you, please let us know what you get when you run the above commands.

Alternately, you will probably have better luck Unicode-wise with the "GHCi" program (which, admittedly, has a less nice GUI).